# Floating Vanity w/ Metal Studs & Tile Wall

Tags: bathroom, vanity

So the high level question I have is, what is the best way to hang a vanity on a wall with metal studs and large format tile (12x24 inches). At this point, I am down to the drywall so can add re-enforcement behind if needed. The tile hasn't been laid so this allows for potential tweaks in the order of operations.

Things to know:

1. 18th Floor Condo
2. Metal studs
3. Tile will be 12 x 24 inches
4. Two cabinets are from Prodigy Cabinetry :
   24" H x 30" W x 22" D   ( Two Doors )
   24" H x 12" W x 22" D   ( Three drawers )
5. The countertop will be 3 CM quartz (unsure of weight, but it'll be a lot)
6. The cabinets will have two walls: one on the back and one on the right.

Questions:

1. I bought the cabinets with the express purposing of hanging with quartz countertops, but I'm not sure if I can tell if they will be able to hold the weight of the quartz plus some. (I'd like to be sure I human could put their weight on it in the event that someone does) So how can I be sure the cabinets were built to hold this weight?
2. What, if any, special techniques would you use to mount it? (extra bracing, anchors, etc)
3. Should I lay the tile first or last? If first, does the tile layer need to leave holes or anything for the mounting?
4. Should studs be added or brace the existing ones?

Comment: Just to confirm: You plan to have cabinets that are *hanging* from the wall and **not** also being supported directly by the floor? Or are they hanging in the proverbial sense (and getting some stability from the wall) but with the weight actually supported by the floor? That makes a *huge* difference.

Comment: The vanity will be hanging from the wall. Mounted on the wall. Not touching the ground.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: It clarifies. My answer would be: "No way". But I'll leave it to the experts as my metal stud experience is relatively limited, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't be doing that. There's enough flex in the stud flanges that you'll see substantial bounce. Look for a vanity with decorative posts, or add your own.

Comment: Thanks. Already got the cabinets almost a year ago now, been waiting on other things. Guess we’ll need to find a way to put some legs?

Comment: If you are willing to cut open the drywall, can you just add wood blocking and/or sister wood joists? Maybe mount a plywood plate/cleat system to spread out the load across multiple joists